# Uipath bot scheduling in orchestrator

Tags: uipath-robot, uipath-orchestrator

I need to schedule the execution of two bots running on two different robots in the UiPath orchestrator. I want the second bot to start executing when first bot execution has completed.
For example, I have 2 bots A and B.. Bot B will be scheduled at 6pm every day, So at 5:45pm bot A has to execute (i.e. 15 minutes prior to Bot B Bot A has to be executed) and if the result of Bot A is false then it should not execute bot B. If bot A result is true then it should execute Bot B.

*Note: Bot A response will be either TRUE or FALSE. (Based on it Bot B has to execute)

Please help me out if you have any solution for the above issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve this.

The first way is simpler, but you don't have much control here. Within Process A (executed by Bot A), you can have an "If" activity that triggers the start of Process B (executed by Bot B):

[image]

This is simple, but doesn't give you much control over which robot is allocated to perform job B if multiple robots are available. You can limit this by assigning only one bot (Bot B) to the environment of Process B.

If you wish to control which specific bot is triggered, you can do that using the orchestrator API. You can configure the API by navigating to your orchestrator tenant's swagger site. The URL for this site looks like this...

[https://platform.uipath.com/[AccountLogicalName]/[TenantLogicalName]/swagger/ui/index#/](https://platform.uipath.com/%5BAccountLogicalName%5D/%5BTenantLogicalName%5D/swagger/ui/index#/)

... for an enterprise orchestrator.

and like this...

[https://cloud.uipath.com/[AccountLogicalName]/[TenantLogicalName]/orchestrator_/swagger/index.html#](https://cloud.uipath.com/%5BAccountLogicalName%5D/%5BTenantLogicalName%5D/orchestrator_/swagger/index.html#)

... for a community orchestrator.

In the swagger link, navigate to Jobs to configure your trigger.

**Important**: For executing either approach, you need to enable the Robot role on orchestrator to have the following permissions:

**Create** and **Edit** rights on jobs, as well as **View** on processes and environments.